# Landmasking in SAR geotiff image?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, land-cover, extract-by-mask, python-3, ocean

I am working on masking land in a SAR geotiff grayscale image. The image is a tilted one and as I am new to this field, I do not know how to proceed.

Also, I searched about rsgislib which provides land masking feature but it is available in Linux and I am working in conda python 3.5 on Windows.

How do I perform landmasking in geotiff image?

Comment: Do you already have a mask showing areas of land you wish to apply to an image to mask out land pixels or are you looking to produce a mask of land from the SAR image? Are you specifically looking for a solution in Python?

Comment: I have a DEM tile of that area but for masking the resolution of DEM tile and SAR image are different.Kindly suggest how to use this DEM tile or is there any other method for masking out land.

Answer (score 1):

First we have to download an appropriate shapefile of the region we wish to mask, then there is a beautiful functionality available in gdal called as gdalwarp. We need to just open the anaconda prompt and from there just type in

gdalwarp -cutline shapefile_name.shp original_image.tif output_filename.tif
Now, the image with borderlines of the land will get saved in the file output_filename.tif 
This is the file which contains the land portion and the ocean is masked out.

Then the procedure becomes fairly simple mask out the land by subtracting the output_filename.tif image from original image.

We will get the image of the ocean part with land portion in black, after that we can make the land portion as nan.